# Send array in JS to php

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to do something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793891/send-selects-values-in-array).
I want to send to the server the id's of the selected checkboxes. I'm using jquery only because the example. my ajax code is pure JS.

This is my code:

js:

```
function DeleteTest(ind)
 {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this test?'))
      {
    ​   $(function() {
       var testdel = $('input[name=deletetest]').serialize();
       alert(testdel);
       window.open('test.php' + "?"+testdel,'_self');
           }   ​);
        return true;}
         else { return false;}
 }
  oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='deletetest' value='"+ ind +   "')';>"; // create checkbox for each row in ajax
```

html:

```
<form id="checkboxform" action="test.php" method="post">
<tbody id="auditTblBody">
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Submit AJAX Request" onclick="DeleteTest()" />
</form>
```

With this code i get only one value with GET.`testdel` is fine. (i.e `deletetest=477&deletetest=476`) my problem is how to send this information.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For PHP to recognize multiple values from inputs with the same name, that name must end in the characters `[]`.

```
  oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='deletetest[]' value='"+ ind +   "')';>";
```

Comment: The name has changed. You have to update the selector to match.

Comment: I changed to `var testdel = $('input[name=deletetest[]]').serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

```
O/p: deletetest=477&deletetest=476
```

send the o/p in json format to a particular php file from javascript  & you can decode it in redirected php file using json_decode